# angularjs ngSlide on $modal create only single instance on swipe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, ui.bootstrap

in angularjs i am using ngAside. its a plugin for `angularjs` based on `ui.bootstrap $modal`.

In my code i am using `ng-swipe` such as `ng-swipe-left` and `ng-swipe-right`.
the problem is that on swipe there are multiple sliding menus are opened.
it works well when put with button bt when implemented with swipe gestures 
it opens multiple instances. is there anyway i can open only 1 instance for each swipe

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="globalCtrl" ng-cloak ng-swipe-right="openScrollModal('right')" ng-swipe-left="openScrollModal('left')">
<div ng-include="'menus/navmenu/navmenu.html'" ng-show="showMenu"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="slide-left" ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("globalCtrl",function($aside,$scope,$rootScope,$location,$modal)
{
   $rootScope.openScrollModal = function(scroll)
  {
    log(scroll);
    log($location.path());
    if($rootScope.isAuthenticated)
    {
    if(scroll=="right")
    {
    $aside.open({
       templateUrl : 'modals/leftSlide/LeftSlide.html',
       placement: 'left',
       size: 'sm',
      show: false
     });
   }
   if(scroll=="left")
   {
   $aside.open({
      templateUrl : 'modals/rightSlide/rightSlide.html',
      placement: 'right',
      size: 'sm',
       show: false
    });
  }
  }
  else
  {
    log("Not Authenticated..Cannot Slide Menu");
  }

  } 

});
```

Comment: When you log(scroll) what is it outputting? Can you copy & paste it exactly?

Comment: its console.log i have just overwritten the function